# service discovery in microservices Vs service discovery in docker

Tags: docker, microservices, docker-swarm, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I am a little confused about the difference between these two. 
Docker swarm provides service discovery for the services that run in it.
In a microservice architecture, each microservices run in one of the containers. Do I need a separate service discovery that is provided by some of the API Gateways or any service discovery frameworks like Eureka, Zookeeper, etc?

Is there any added advantage if I use some specific service discovery frameworks other than that is provided by Docker Swarm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need a separate service discovery that is provided by some of the
>   API Gateways or any service discovery frameworks like Eureka,
>   Zookeeper, etc?

If your micro services are deployed as docker swarm services within the same swarm you don't need additional service discovery mechanism. 
Each docker service can connect to another by its service name.

Comment: Thank you. I guess there is no advantage in using other frameworks like performance, security etc.